# ANSIBLE - no action detected in task

Tags: ansible

This is the offending line where the error seems to be:

```
- name: Generate random password
  vars: 
    jupyter_pwd: "{{ lookup('password', '/root/jupyter_password length=10') }}"
```

I'm trying to generate a random password and store it in the `jupyter_pwd` variable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not how Ansible works. It's not like i.e. bash's variable expansion. In Ansible you need to use specified action (command) to do the task - in this case you need to use the task that would support executing shell commands or scripts. This middle layer is needed because Ansible can run your playbook on any target host, be it remote or local machine, with the same unaltered playbook. Therefore it needs to provide middle man for any task to be able to do that and this is what Ansible's actions are for.

In your case you most likely need [command](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/modules/command_module.html) action:

```
- name: "Generate random password"
  command: command-to-execute 
  register: jupyter_pwd
```

Where `command-to-execute` is binary or script on remote host you want to run. Whatever that `command-to-execute` returns is captured and made available as `jupyter_pwd` variable to the rest of your playbook.
See [docs] for more information.

If `command` action is too strict (which may be if you want to chain several shell tools), then [shell](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/modules/shell_module.html) action may be the way to go instead.